# TYPO3 RTE: How to prevent nesting of tags (eg. H1>A)

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x

How can i configure the TYPO3 RTE htmlarea so that either:

- A nesting of a `a-tag` within a `h1-tag` is not possible with the UI or
- That a nested `a-tag` inside a `h1-tag` is not stored in the DB

As you can see [here](http://books.google.de/books?id=xayL0Ckq60kC&pg=PT166&lpg=PT166&dq=exitHTMLparser_rte&source=bl&ots=pMywKXW9QG&sig=5HlltEQUugElQMI-QIMFBKqzrTQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ecb7UtK4AuKM7Ab654CwCg&ved=0CFQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Die%20vier%20optionalen,%20RTE-unab&f=false) i thing it should be done with one of these

- `RTE.default.proc.entryHTMLparser_db`
- `RTE.default.proc.exitHTMLparser_db`
- Or the cloud in the middle (Page-TSconfig / RTE.proc)

I thing the HTMLparser are not able to prevent nesting.
What other options are available for this task?